How can I stop pandas from plotting weekend dates for 5T frequency data when there is no weekend data?
I have the following 5-minute frequency time series data for weekdays only:
start_date = '2024-09-06 00:00:00'
end_date = '2024-09-10 00:00:00'
dt_index = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='5T')
dt_index = dt_index[dt_index.weekday < 5] # remove weekend days

data = np.random.randn(len(dt_index))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dt_index, columns=['Random_Data'])
df



There are no weekend dates or weekend data in the dataframe, but this is what I get when I plot it:

How can I stop pandas from plotting the weekend dates? I only want to plot weekdays - I don't want any gaps or straight connected lines where there aren't any dates or data.
The answer that was suggested as a duplicate to my question suggests adding back missing data, getting rid of null values, and/or plotting a gap instead of line for missing data. My data is not missing data so there is nothing to add back, nor does it have any null values. Please don't close this question.

@mrconcerned you can just use the code provided to generate the dataframe

this can be achieved by manually setting the x_ticks:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_date = '2024-09-06 00:00:00'
end_date = '2024-09-10 00:00:00'
dt_index = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='5T')

dt_index = dt_index[dt_index.weekday < 5]

data = np.random.randn(len(dt_index))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dt_index, columns=['Random_Data'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(df.index, df['Random_Data'])

# Configure the x-axis to only show the dates from the data
plt.gca().set_xticks(df.index[::12 * 24])  # Adjust ticks for clarity, e.g., every 12*24 data points (once per day)
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(df.index[::12 * 24].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'), rotation=45)

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Random Data')
plt.title('Time Series Data Without Weekends')
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


I get an empty plot when I run your code.

for me it shows a graph with only weekdays on x-axis
